# Weird whitespace character on the side of <img> tag

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to create header of website. When I started create it, I notice one weird behavior of text tags (from `h1` to `p`, `spans` and etc.). It adds that whitespace on the side of image where text is located.

```css
header {
  padding-top: 10px;
}

header .container-fluid .row>* {
  height: 8rem;
}

header .logo>* {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

header .logo .img {
  height: 100%;
}

header .logo .title {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="logo col-12 col-md-auto">
        <img class="img" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/11/12/13/37/forest-2942477__340.jpg">
        <p class="title">Any text causes strange behavior</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

If you still don't understand what I'm talking about, here is screenshot:[image]

See this blue line? This is that weird whitespace.

---

UPD 1:

I changed `padding-left: 0.5rem;` to `margin-left: 0.5rem;` but whitespace is still here.

UPD2:

Also found a solution thanks to **`Matt Croak`** for link.
Solution is to add `font-size:0` to `logo` block and set `font-size: initial;` or font-size: 16px; to `header .logo .title`.

Comment: my guess is that it comes from your `padding-left` style on the `header .logo .title` selector

Comment: Please provide information about your browser. If possible, reproduce the problem in Browser Stack. It doesn't seems to be a common problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to do with your `img` and your HTML being on on multiple lines. If you put your `img` and `p` HTML on the same line (no space between) it goes away. `img`'s are rendered as `display: inline-block;` by default. Items that are `inline-block` behave like words in a sentence and therefore have inherent white space between them.

You can read more about it [here](http://www.codeblocq.com/2016/09/The-mysterious-4px-gap-in-between-images/).

```css
header {
  padding-top: 10px;
}

header .container-fluid .row>* {
  height: 8rem;
}

header .logo>* {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

header .logo .img {
  height: 100%;
}

header .logo .title {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="logo col-12 col-md-auto">
        <img class="img" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/11/12/13/37/forest-2942477__340.jpg">
        <p class="title">Any text causes strange behavior</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the whitespace in your code between the paragraph and image:

```css
header {
  padding-top: 10px;
}

header .container-fluid .row>* {
  height: 8rem;
}

header .logo>* {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

header .logo .img {
  height: 100%;
}

header .logo .title {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="logo col-12 col-md-auto">
        <img class="img" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/11/12/13/37/forest-2942477__340.jpg"><p class="title">Any text causes strange behavior</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Why does it happens? I personally find it a little strange.

Comment: @PythonNewbie The browser renders whitespace in inline elements

Comment: `img`'s are rendered as `display: inline-block;` by default. Items that are `inline-block` behave like words in a sentence and therefore have inherent white space between them. More [here](http://www.codeblocq.com/2016/09/The-mysterious-4px-gap-in-between-images/)

Answer (score -1):

Padding seems to be ok.

The so called whitespace is caused by the spaces/newline between the img and the p tag.

If you change your html format like below, the whitespace is gone.

```
<header>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="logo col-12 col-md-auto">
        <img class="img" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/11/12/13/37/forest-2942477__340.jpg"><p class="title">Any text causes strange behavior</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: I tried it inside a `<b>` and `<strong>` tag and the space is still there.